# Finding the Minimum value of an interpolating function

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I can't seem to use `FindMinValue` to find the min. value of a curve represented by an interpolating function.

For instance the below code generates an interpolating function polynomial as the solution of the heat equation.

```
tsol = u /. 
  NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
     u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}][[1]]
```

This plots it:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. %], {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I'd like to find the minimum point in the curve represented by this function at say, `t=10.0`, , so I try doing this:

```
FindMinValue[tsol, {{x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 10}}]
```

Which is obviously wrong. I'd like to find the minimum value AT t=10.

This didn't work either:

```
FindMinValue[tsol[10, x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

I actually have an interpolating func. which is in `x` `y` and `t` and I am quite flabbergasted.

Why is the Dimensions of `tsol` 5? I thought it'd be 2 since it is only in x and t.

Plot of tsol[10,x]:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen a plot of `tsol[10, x]`?

Comment: @J.M. I just did... I editted my question to include that... However, the images aren't showing at all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is always a good thing to ensure that `InterpolatingFunction`s are called with parameters inside the region:

```
tsol = u /. 
  NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
     u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}][[1]];
Plot3D[tsol[t, x], {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]

FindMinimum[{tsol[t, x], 0 <= t <= 10 && 0 <= x <= 5}, {{x, 1}, {t, 9}}]

(* {-1.00007, {x -> 1.43395*10^-7, t -> 4.71148}} *)
```

This should only give you an idea, although it does not find the minimum you like.

**Update**

And to find the minimum value as pointed out in the last part of your question, you can do

```
Plot[tsol[10, x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
FindMinValue[{tsol[10, x], 0 <= x <= 5}, x]

(*  -0.544147  *)
```

The option-value is `All` to plot everything.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @haliurtan What I wanted to find was the point on the curve at say t=10 which is the minimum. This doesn't find the minimum because the result is actually a sine curve? -ish?

Comment: @drN See my update.

Comment: @haliurtan I tested this for a data set and I find that this method is incorrect. I'll try to post my data set online for you to take a look at if you'd so choose to.

Comment: @haliurtan You will find [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/hmin_data.zip) two data files in .mat format and one .nb which imports the data and tries to find the minimum value of the plot. You'd want to use L=92.389, fac=0.99, thres1 and thresh2 can be set to any value as I am not using them in this code.