# FindMaxValue and FindMaximum - how to find GLOBAL maximum and not just LOCAL maximum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I will not be able to provide a *simple* minimum working example here as this seems to be very specific.

I have an interpolating function which I substituted into a PDE and then plot said PDE at a certain time for x and y.

I'd like to find the global maximum of this function. Finding the maximum was described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13110/204). However, I find that this just finds the local maximum. As soon as the first maximum value is encountered, the FindMaximum or FindMaxValue are stopped and I don't get the global maximum.

For instance, when I run FindMaximum or FindMaxValue on the interpolating function that generates this:

[image]

The local maximum very close to the left bottom corner is returned as **1.7291*10^-6**. Obviously the maximum is around **0.00002**.

### I have attached my .mat files [***here***](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/data.zip). The notebook that I use to plot and calculate maximum is as:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
(*Loads the files*)
L = 79.5788;
fileList = FileNames["L_lambda_max_1wl_zg.mat", NotebookDirectory[]];
fileListxy = FileNames["L_lambda_max_1wl_zg.mat", NotebookDirectory[]];
fileListt = 
  FileNames["L_lambda_max_1wl_zg_time.mat", NotebookDirectory[]];
datat = Import[fileListt[[1]]];
trup = Max[Flatten[datat]];
tsrup = Ceiling[
   0.9 Flatten[Position[Ceiling[Flatten[datat]], Ceiling[trup]]]];
ts = tsrup[[1]];
dataxy = Import[fileListxy[[1]]];
solution = ListInterpolation[dataxy, {{0, L}, {0, L}, Flatten[datat]}];

(*Plots the data at 0.99 final time*)
Plot3D[
 solution[x, y, 0.99 datat // Flatten // Last], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, 
 PlotPoints -> 65]
fac datat // Flatten // Last



(*Defines EqS and plots it and finds the maximum*)
Clear[EqS, EqM]
fac = 0.6;
xg = 0.0
Bi = 1;
Bo = xg 1/300;
K1 = 1;
\[Epsilon] = 10^-6;
\[Delta] = 10^-3;
m = 2*0.025;
r = 0;
EqS = Div[(-h[x, y, t]^3)*Bo*Grad[h[x, y, t]]];


Res[x_, y_, t_] = Abs[EqS /. h -> solution];
EffectofG = 
 Plot3D[Res[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L},
   MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 65, PlotRange -> Automatic]
FindMaxValue[{Res[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last], 0 <= x <= L, 
  0 <= y < L}, x, y]

(*Defines EqnM, plots it and finds the maximum *)

EqM = Div[m*(h[x, y, t]/(K1 + Bi*h[x, y, t]))^2*Grad[h[x, y, t]]];
Clear[ResM];
EqM;
Bi = 1;
K1 = 1;
\[Epsilon] = 10^-6;
\[Delta] = 10^-3;
m = 2*0.025;
r = 0;
ResM[x_, y_, t_] = Abs[EqM /. h -> solution];
EffectofM = 
 Plot3D[ResM[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, 
   L}, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 65]
FindMaxValue[{ResM[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last], 0 <= x <= L, 
  0 <= y <= L}, x, y]
```

This was generated using a massive mathematica script and I don't think it would be to many people's interest to run the script for several hours to generate this data. Hence, I just uploaded the data.

Edit:

As per rm-rf's suggestion (see comments) I tried `NMaximize` with the following change in syntax.

I replaced:

```
FindMaxValue[{ResM[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last], 0 <= x <= L, 
  0 <= y <= L}, x, y]
```

with:

```
NMaximize[{ResM[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last]}, {x, y}]
```

I find that as I increase the value of `fac` in my code to say 0.99 times the end time, it gives me a LOCAL maximum instead of a GLOBAL maximum.

Comment: `FindMaximum` always tries to find only a local maximum, whereas `NMaximize` attempts to find a global maximum. Have you tried using `NMaximize/NMinimize`?

Comment: @rm-rf I tried NMaximize with `NMaximize[{ResM[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last], 0 <= x <= L, 
  0 <= y <= L}, x, y]` but it says that only 2 arguments are expected while I furnished 3. I need to furnish the arguments that I have...

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you simply substitute one with the other. Did you read the documentation to check for the right syntax? Hint: `NMaximize` takes only 2 arguments

Comment: @rm-rf Yes I did read. I guess I don't get why its wrong. I see from the syntax that I need to specify x and y. Are you saying I don't need to specify the limits of x and y?

Comment: `x` and `y` are grouped as `{x, y}`, whereas you haven't in your call... See the third example for the syntax in the docs. I don't know if it'll work; just a guess.

Comment: @rm-rf No luck. I'll restart my kernel and check if all is well.

Comment: @rm-rf Just checked again. `NMaximize` still gives me a local maximum.

Comment: Oh well... was worth a shot. Can't play with it right now, but hopefully someone else can.

Comment: @drN Notice that you use `fac` once before defining it. If I run your notebook and then `NMaximize[{ResM[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last], 0 <= x <= L, 
  0 <= y <= L}, {x, y}]` I get `{0.0000113102, {x -> 79.5788, y -> 79.5788}}`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I'll try that out. You could post that as an answer though.

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to consider using [`FindAllCrossings2D[]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275) on the appropriate derivatives of the function you want to optimize...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the suggestion by @rm-rf works :

```
fac
(* 0.99 *)

sol = NMaximize[{ResM[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last], 0 <= x <= L, 0 <= y <= L}, {x, y}]
(* {0.000335995, {x -> 69.3566, y -> 71.9692}} *)
```

which agrees with the plot :

```
Show[Plot3D[ResM[x, y, fac datat // Flatten // Last], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 65], 
     ListPointPlot3D[{{sol[[2, 1, 2]], sol[[2, 2, 2]], sol[[1]]}}, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Green]]]
```

[image]

Comment: You could also do something like `Show[Plot3D[(* stuff *)], Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[{sol[[2, 1, 2]], sol[[2, 2, 2]], sol[[1]]}, 2]}]]`; adjust the radius of the `Sphere[]` as seen fit.