# Find maximum value of interpolation function - obviously wrong result

Tags: mathematical-optimization, interpolation

Minimizing and maximizing interpolation function has already been asked and answered, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13110/finding-the-minimum-value-of-an-interpolating-function) for example.

Yet, I observe a strange behaviour. Well, I can understand that the wrong guess of Mathematica is due to several maxima, but still I'm surprised I don't manage to get a better result.

### Generation of the considered function

Here is how I get the interpolation function `Theta[t]`:

```
OmegaS = 1.32; OmegaP = 1; l0 = 1; tmax = 100;

eqn1[t_] = r''[t]/l0 - r[t]*theta'[t]^2/l0 + OmegaS^2*(r[t]/l0 - 1) - OmegaP^2*Cos[theta[t]];
eqn2[t_] = r[t]*theta''[t]/l0 + 2 r'[t]*theta'[t]/l0 + OmegaP^2*Sin[theta[t]];

sol = NDSolve[{eqn1[t] == 0, eqn2[t] == 0, r[0] == .9, r'[0] == 0, 
theta[0] == 0.001, theta'[0] == 0}, {r, theta}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];

Theta[t_] = theta[t] /. sol
```

This is what `Theta` looks like:

```
Plot[Theta[t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All,  AxesLabel -> {"t", "Theta(t)"}]
```

[image: plot Theta]

### Attempts to identify the maximum

I now want to find the maximum of `Theta[t]` for $t\in[0,100]$. I underline that the peak could be *anywhere* in $[0,100]$ so I cannot indicate any relevant initial guess.

I tried all the following solutions, which obviously give an incorrect result:

```
MaxValue[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t]
(* 0.243314 *)
NMaxValue[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t]
(* 0.243314 *)
FindMaximum[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t]
(* {0.000999881, {t -> 0.0146385}} *)
Maximize[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t]
(* {0.243314, {t -> 92.1206}} *)
NMaximize[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t]
(* {0.243314, {t -> 92.1206}} *)
```

The best (inelegant) way I found to approximate the maximum is brute-force:

```
Max[Table[Theta[i], {i, 0, tmax, .001}]]
(* 0.687071 *)
```

### Question

Do you know:

- why my attempts fail?
- a good way to find the (global!) maximum?

Comment: You use FindMaximum, which only looks for a local maximum.  It would do what you want if you gave it a starting point near the peak you were interested in: FindMaximum[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, {t, 50}].  You could try NMaximize, which tries to find a global maximum, but I doubt that will work very well for arbitrary interpolating functions.

Comment: @KAI Unfortunately the peak can be anywhere in $[0,100]$. I hadn't put `NMaximize` in the list but I guess `Maximize` automatically switched to `NMaximize`. Anyway, the give the same (wrong) answer, unfortunately. [I'll add `NMaximize` in my question].

Comment: Probably the only foolproof way would be to peer into the internal structure of the `InterpolatingFunction`: it does a piecewise polynomial interpolation, and one might be able to reliably find the maximum of each piece. Unfortunately I'm afraid I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Pickett: True! But `Minimize[{-Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t]` does not work.

Comment: @anderstood Ah yes, I deleted my comment when I realized. Thanks for asking this question, I learned something from it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As described e.g. in the tutorial [Numerical Nonlinear Global Optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html) there are different optimization methods available.
For your problem `"SimulatedAnnealing"` seems to work:

```
NMaximize[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]
```

> ```
> {0.687071, {t -> 48.2449}}
> ```

`"DifferentialEvolution"` will work, if the population is of sufficient size:

```
NMaximize[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> 30}]
```

`"RandomSearch"` will also work, if the number of points used to start local searches is big enough, e.g. bigger than 13 for your example.

```
NMaximize[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t, Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 14}]
```

Comment: Did you randomly try different methods or did you try this one for some particular reason(s)? Thank you anyway.

Comment: @anderstood It was my first guess, because "SimulatedAnnealing" uses multiple starting points.

Comment: Map onto all methods and select one that works best:  {#, NMaximize[{Theta[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t, Method -> #]} & /@ { Automatic, "DifferentialEvolution", "NelderMead", "RandomSearch", "SimulatedAnnealing"} // Grid

Comment: I unaccepted you question (before your edit) because the solution with `SimulatedAnnealing` is not very robust: it does not work if you change `OmegaS` to `1.96`. I'm going to try the other suggestion right now, thank you.

Comment: @anderstood Robustness will increase, if you increase the number of initial points. It can also be increased for "SimulatedAnnealing", e.g. `Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", "SearchPoints" -> 50}`

Comment: OK, TY @BobHanlon and Karsten 7. I will use only one method with many SearchPoints, as suggested by Karsten 7. If it happened to be not robust enough even for many SearchPoints, I would switch to the costly but powerful method proposed by Bob! (which can even be combined with many SearchPoints :D)

Comment: @Karsten7. Don't you think that it is a bit more complicated? I assume you compared several methods for `"SearchPoints" -> 100`, but maybe `"SimulatedAnnealing"` is as accurate with only `70` points... Well I have all what I need to investigate on my own, thank you very much indeed!

Comment: @anderstood I tried different number of points. But now I see that the speed depends on your `OmegaS`. For `OmegaS = 1.32` "SimulatedAnnealing" is faster, for `OmegaS = 1.96` "RandomSearch" is faster. So, you are right, it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Karsten7. I think that's why we speak of *numerical recipes*! It's really like cooking :)

Answer (score 15):

Two approaches: Finding maxima (1) of an [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) and (2) via [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html).

### `InterpolatingFunction`

To find the extrema of an `InterpolatingFunction`, one should start with the data contained in the function.

Let's start with the function itself;

```
ifn = theta /. sol
```

Then `ifn["Grid"]` and `ifn["VaiuesOnGrid"]` contain the abscissas (`t`) and ordinates (`theta[t]`) computed by `NDSolve`.  We should start our search for a maximum near the maximum value stored in `ifn`.  The position of the maximum can be calculated with [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html).  So the best starting point is found with

```
{{t0}} = ifn["Grid"] ~Part~ Ordering[ifn["ValuesOnGrid"], -1]
(* {{48.2466}} *)
```

Then one can use `FindMaximum`:

```
FindMaximum[ifn[t], {t, t0}]

(* FindMaximum::lstol complaint... *)

(* {0.687071, {t -> 48.24493512854019`}} *)
```

If the complaint is worrisome, then one can check the result by plotting the result, increasing working precision or trying, say, `NMaximize`.  These return the same solution with no warnings:

```
FindMaximum[ifn[t], {t, t0}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]

NMaximize[{ifn[t], 0 < t < 100}, t,  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "InitialPoints" -> {{t0}}}]
```

### `NDSolve`

An easier approach, if the `InterpolatingFunction` was created with `NDSolve`, is to use [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html).  One can detect a local maximum with the event `theta'[t] < 0`, where the derivative becomes negative, and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) the corresponding values of `t` and `theta[t]`.  Then one selects the absolute maximum among them with `Ordering`.

```
{sol, {localmax}} = 
  Reap[NDSolveValue[{eqn1[t] == 0, eqn2[t] == 0, r[0] == .9, 
     r'[0] == 0, theta[0] == 0.001, theta'[0] == 0,
     WhenEvent[theta'[t] < 0, Sow[{theta[t], {t1 -> t}}]]},
     {r, theta}, {t, 0, tmax}]
   ];

# ~Part~ First@Ordering[#[[All, 1]], -1] &@ localmax

(* {0.687071, {t1 -> 48.2449}} *)
```

Index for the last line of code:

```
localmax                   :  a list of local maxima in the form {{y.yyy, {t1 -> x.xxx}},...}
#[[All, 1]]                :  {y.yyy,...} -- list of local maxima
First@
 Ordering[#[[All, 1]], -1] :  position of the greatest local maximum = global maximum
# ~Part~ ""                :  extracts the part of localmax that is the global maximum
```

### Re global maximization -- updated

In general, global optimization is difficult, especially when there are many local extrema.  Finding all of them can be uncertain and time consuming.  In turn one cannot be certain about the global extremum found.  Sometimes personal insight has to be applied to optimizing a given objective function.

In this case there seems to be an issue with precision in the `InterpolatingFunction`.  Starting with the critical points found above, if we examine the values of `ifn`, we see that they constant in a neighborhood of the critical point.  This probably has something to do with the optimization problem, and almost certainly with the `FindMaximum::lstol` message.

```
tfindroot = {t -> 48.24493512854019`};  (* FindRoot *)
tndsolve  = {t -> 48.24493514514225`};  (* NDSolve *)

Table[ifn[t (1 + 2^20 $MachineEpsilon dt)] - ifn[t] /. tfindroot, {dt, -2, 2}]
Table[ifn[t (1 + 2^20 $MachineEpsilon dt)] - ifn[t] /. tndsolve, {dt, -2, 2}]
(*
  {-3.33067*10^-16, -2.22045*10^-16, 0., 0., 0.}
  {-1.11022*10^-16, 0., 0., 0., -1.11022*10^-16}
*)

Table[ifn[t (1 + 2^21 $MachineEpsilon dt)] - ifn[t] /. tfindroot, {dt, -2, 2}]
Table[ifn[t (1 + 2^21 $MachineEpsilon dt)] - ifn[t] /. tndsolve, {dt, -2, 2}]
(*
  {-9.99201*10^-16, -3.33067*10^-16, 0., 0., -2.22045*10^-16}
  {-5.55112*10^-16, -1.11022*10^-16, 0., -1.11022*10^-16, -5.55112*10^-16}
*)
```

Interestingly, using arbitrary precision helps `NMaximize` on the posted problem, but it does not work for all values of the parameter `OmegaS`.  Sample code:

```
sol = First@NDSolve[
   Rationalize@
    {eqn1[t] == 0, eqn2[t] == 0, r[0] == 0.9, 
     r'[0] == 0, theta[0] == 0.001, theta'[0] == 0},
   {r, theta}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision];
    ifn = theta /. sol;
    NMaximize[{ifn[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]
(* {0.6870714027852798, {t -> 48.24493489787723}} *)
```

The `NDSolve` method is probably the best way to proceed.  Theoretically, if there are local maxima that are close in value to the global maximum, then one of them might be returned instead of the global one.  But they would have to be very close, within the error of the `NDSolve` computation.  If one wanted further evidence, one could use the `"RandomSearch"` method of `NMaximize` with the local maxima (`localmax` from the `NDSolve` approach above) as initial points:

```
NMaximize[ifn[t], t, 
 Method -> {"RandomSearch", "InitialPoints" -> ({t1} /. localmax[[All, -1]])}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]
(* {0.6870714027850805, {t1 -> 48.24493514549923}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for this very instructive answer, which I have not tried yet. I guess you meant `ifn["..."]` instead of `if["..."]` in the first paragraph but I prefer to let you change it, if need be.

Comment: @anderstood You're welome, and thanks for pointing out `if`.  I changed from `if` to `ifn` because `if` looked too much like an English word.  Guess I missed some.

Comment: +1 for the `WhenEvent[]` idea. Never thought about that use before. Great.

Comment: Nowadays, `PeakDetect[]` is a usable alternative for the first approach in this answer.