# How to generate pure function solution using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose i have an equation

```
NDSolve[{ca'[t]== -0.1*ca[t]*cb[t], cb'[t]== -0.1*2*ca[t]*cb[t], 
  ca[0]== 10, cb[0]== 12},{ca,cb},{t,0,5}]
```

how can i get the solution in pure function form(even if i don't consider time limit) of above equation.

There is an option with [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) to get pure function for linear DE.
But how to deal with non linear DE to get pure function ?

Answer (score 3):

What you get as result are `InterpolatingFunction` objects. These can be used like pure functions. Therefore, you can transform the result of `NDSolve` so that you can call it like a function:

```
sol = NDSolve[{ca'[t] == -0.1*ca[t]*cb[t],cb'[t] == -0.1*2*ca[t]*cb[t], 
  ca[0] == 10, cb[0] == 12}, {ca, cb}, {t, 0, 5}];

f = With[{exp = Through[({ca, cb} /. First[sol])[#]]}, exp &];
```

Now you can use `f`

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Does this help?

Comment: actually i was looking for the solution in form {{ca->Function[{t},........], cb->Function[{t},.....]}} so that i can further use this function for optimization

Comment: @swapnil90 You cannot use `NDSolve` to get a symbolic solution, except in terms of `InterpolatingFunction`.  You can optimize such solutions.  See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58244), the question linked in it, and their answers.  If they don't address your situation and you can find nothing else on the site that does, consider asking another question about how to do exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In V10, `DSolve` gives the answer:

```
{sol} = DSolve[
  {ca'[t] == -1/10*ca[t]*cb[t], cb'[t] == -1/10*2*ca[t]*cb[t], ca[0] == 10, cb[0] == 12},
  {ca, cb}, t]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> ```
> (*
>   {{cb -> Function[{t}, 24/(-3 + 5 E^(4 t/5))], 
>     ca -> Function[{t}, (20 E^(4 t/5))/(-3 + 5 E^(4 t/5))]}}
> *)
> ```

```
Plot[{ca[t], cb[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]