# Using ParametricNDSolve and NMinimize to find accurate interplanetary trajectory arrival periapse radius

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions, astronomy

I have an interplanetary trajectory simulation that calculates the required velocity (using a Lambert solver) and escape angle for a spacecraft to travel from Earth to Mars. This model does not use a patched conic approximation (where trajectory segments are "patched" together), but instead uses a fully integrated approach where the gravitational attraction of the Earth, Mars and Sun all act on the spacecraft concurrently at any given time in the simulation. As such, the spacecraft's escape angle from low-Earth orbit (which is calculated using patched-conic equations) is not accurate enough to produce a trajectory that will hit Mars directly, and is usually off by quite a lot (about 10%-20%) due to the pull of Earth's gravitational field when the spacecraft leaves Earth.

Thus, what I've tried to do is use `ParametricNDSolve` and `NMinimize` to perform numerical optimization and scan through a parameter `p` that acts as an escape angle "correction coefficient". The optimizer scans through values of p until it finds the desired value of p that will correct the Earth ejection angle and give an accurate trajectory that reaches Mars at a predefined periapse radius (which is 300km above Mars' surface in this case as shown in the code below).

Below is a stripped down version (it excludes the Lambert solver and various other calculations that do not need to be shown)  of the simulation code that shows the optimization process:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
(*Gravitational Constant*)
G = 6.672*10^-11;
(*Simulation running time, in seconds (1 day = 86400 seconds)*)
tmax = (1000) (86400);
(*Spacecraft time-of-flight between Earth and Mars, in seconds (1 day = 86400 seconds)*)
TOF = (254) (86400);
(*Mass of Sun, Earth, Mars (from JPL's Horizons ephemeris), in kilograms*)
ms = 1.988544*10^30 ;(*Mass of Sun*)
me = 5.97219*10^24 ;(*Mass of Earth*)
mm = 6.4185*10^23 ;(*Mass of Mars*)
(*Planetary radii of Sun, Earth and Mars (from JPL's Horizons ephemeris), in metres*)
r[0] = 6.963*10^8 ;(*Mean radius of Sun*) 
r[1] = 6.37101 *10^6;(*Mean radius of Earth*) 
r[2] = 3.3899*10^6 ;(*Mean radius of Mars*)
(*Heliocentric positions of Earth and Mars (from JPL's Horizons ephemeris) on 26 November 2011, in metres*)
pe = 149597870700 {4.416639858432274*10^-1, 8.798967504313304*10^-1} ;
pm = 149597870700 {-8.159382724017646*10^-1, 1.414986880765974*10^0};
(*Heliocentric velocities of Earth and Mars (from JPL's Horizons ephemeris) on 26 November 2011, in metres*)
ve = 149597870700/86400 {-1.563974110293042*10^-2, 7.690252775639107*10^-3};
vm = 149597870700/86400 {-1.160326991502370*10^-2, -5.778933879736245*10^-3} ;
(*Hyperbolic excess velocity, in metres per second. Difference between spacecraft's Heliocentric velocity vLambert[1] and Earth's Heliocentric velocity ve*)
vinf = Norm[{-29134.32, 15779.21} - ve];
(*Earth orbital radius of departure hyperbola, in metres*)
rp = (r[1] + 300000);
(*Earth ejection angle, in radians*)
e = 6.37526

(*Interplanetary transfer trajectory model*)
(*Models the motion of Earth (xe, ye), Mars (xm, ym) and spacecraft (xsc, ysc) in a Cartesian coordinate system*)
Soln = ParametricNDSolve[{
   xe''[t] == -((G ms xe[t])/(xe[t]^2 + ye[t]^2)^(3/2)),
   ye''[t] == -((G ms ye[t])/(xe[t]^2 + ye[t]^2)^(3/2)),
   xm''[t] == -((G ms xm[t])/(xm[t]^2 + ym[t]^2)^(3/2)),
   ym''[t] == -((G ms ym[t])/(xm[t]^2 + ym[t]^2)^(3/2)),
   xsc''[t] == -((G ms xsc[t])/(xsc[t]^2 + ysc[t]^2)^(3/2)) - (G me (xsc[t] - xe[t]))/((xsc[t] - xe[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ye[t])^2)^(3/2) - (G mm (xsc[t] - xm[t]))/((xsc[t] - xm[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ym[t])^2)^(3/2),
   ysc''[t] == -((G ms ysc[t])/(xsc[t]^2 + ysc[t]^2)^(3/2)) - (G me (ysc[t] - ye[t]))/((xsc[t] - xe[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ye[t])^2)^(3/2) - (G mm (ysc[t] - ym[t]))/((xsc[t] - xm[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ym[t])^2)^(3/2),

   xe[0] == pe[[1]], ye[0] == pe[[2]], xm[0] == pm[[1]], 
   ym[0] == pm[[2]], xsc[0] == pe[[1]] + (r[1] + 300000) Cos[e p], 
   ysc[0] == pe[[2]] + (r[1] + 300000) Sin[e p], xe'[0] == ve[[1]], 
   ye'[0] == ve[[2]], xm'[0] == vm[[1]], ym'[0] == vm[[2]], 
   xsc'[0] == ve[[1]] - Sqrt[vinf^2 + (2 G me)/rp] Sin[e p], 
   ysc'[0] == ve[[2]] + Sqrt[vinf^2 + (2 G me)/rp] Cos[e p]}, {xe[t], 
   ye[t], xm[t], ym[t], xsc[t], ysc[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, {p}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> 10000000]

(*Plot of interplanetary trajectory before ejection angle "fix"*)
Orbits = ParametricPlot[{{xe[t][1], ye[t][1]}, {xm[t][1], ym[t][1]}, {xsc[t][1], ysc[t][1]}} /. Soln, {t, 0, TOF}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {{-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12}, {-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12}}]

(*Finding value for parameter p that will fix the Earth ejection angle and produce the desired orbital radius upon Mars intercept*)
(*Constrained spacecraft to target an orbit of 300km above Mars*)
(*Constrained time search to be 10 days before and 10 days after "ideal" intercept time TOF*)
rm = NMinimize[{(Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] + (r[2] + 300000)) /. Soln, TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 0.8 < p < 1}, {t, p}, Method -> "NelderMead"]

(*Orbital radius above Mars's surface, in metres*)
rm[[1]] - r[2]
(*Parameter value that gives closest approach*)
pmin = Last[Last[Last[rm]]] 
(*Time of closest approach, in seconds*)
tp = Last[rm[[2]][[1]]] 

(*Plot of interplanetary trajectory after ejection angle "fix"*)
Orbits = ParametricPlot[{{xe[t][pmin], ye[t][pmin]}, {xm[t][pmin], ym[t][pmin]}, {xsc[t][pmin], ysc[t][pmin]}} /. Soln, {t, 0, tp}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {{-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12}, {-0.25*10^12, 0.25*10^12}}]

(*Animation of interplanetary trajectory after ejection angle "fix"*)
OrbitAnimation = Animate[ParametricPlot[{{xe[t][pmin], ye[t][pmin]}, {xm[t][pmin], ym[t][pmin]}, {xsc[t][pmin], ysc[t][pmin]}} /. Soln /. t -> a, {t, 0, a}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {{-0.3*10^12, 0.3*10^12}, {-0.3*10^12, 0.3*10^12}}], {a, 0, tmax}, AnimationRate -> 1000000]
```

As it stands, the optimization seems to work very well and manages to find a value for `p` within a few seconds that will give an orbital radius of 301.428km above Mars' surface upon intercept.

Below is the original "unfixed" trajectory:

[image]

And here is the fixed trajectory using the optimizer:

[image]

However, `ParametricNDSolve` uses relatively low values of `AccuracyGoal -> 10` and `PrecisionGoal -> 10`. Tests using higher values of `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` produced very different results when the spacecraft came close to Mars (as seen below when the simulation was run for 1000 days) (note that the trajectories shown below were found by trial-and-error instead of using the optimizer):

Trajectory using `AccuracyGoal -> 10` and `PrecisionGoal -> 10`:

[image]

Trajectory using `AccuracyGoal -> 18` and `PrecisionGoal -> 18`:

[image]

As can be seen above, the two trajectory outputs are qualitatively very different and this is likely due to error accumulated when the trajectory changes rapidly as it passes close to Mars.

As such, I'm hoping to be able to use as high a value of `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` as possible in order to minimize error and it seems like a value of 18 would do the trick. However, when using  `AccuracyGoal -> 18` and `PrecisionGoal -> 18` the optimizer comes to a complete standstill, and unfortunately it becomes much quicker to just calculate the Earth ejection angle correction by trial-and-error.

I'm hoping that some Mathematica experts may be able to shed some light on my horribly inefficient code, as I'm desperately hoping to not have to go back to using trial-and-error to find a trajectory fix! Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if more information is required I'll be happy to supply it. Thanks very much.

EDIT:

After reading the replies and doing a little more testing, I felt that something was very wrong. I adjusted the Mars arrival periapse distance from `r[2] + 300000` (300km above Mars' surface) (this is a bit of code that sits in the `NMinimize` function and acts as a constraint) to an order of magnitude higher (`r[2] + 3000000` or 3000km above Mars' surface) and found no difference in the output trajectory when the simulation was run for 1000 seconds (change `tp` to `TOF` in the `Orbits` time variable to see this). I then started to increase the arrival periapse distance by an order of magnitude iteratively until I found a change in the output trajectory. This only occurred at `r[2] + 30000000000000000` which is clearly not correct!

Aside from the issue of using `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` instead of `SetPrecision` and `WorkingPrecision` I wonder if it's something wrong in my code or if `ParametricNDSolve` or `NMinimize` are not working correctly in this instance. It would be very helpful if someone else could possibly see if they have the same strange behavior as I did using the code.

Comment: A couple of naive observations: (1) Have you tried using arbitrary precsion?  That is, `WorkingPrecision -> 16`.  The general rule of thumb *Mathematica* uses is that the `PrecisionGoal/AccuracyGoal` is set (unless overidden) to one-half the `WorkingPrecision`.  (You should increase the precision of your coefficients to match `WorkingPrecision`; see `SetPrecision`.)  (2) `FindMinimum` ought to be faster than `NMinimize` and might be just as reliable, if you can give it a good starting point.  And minimizing the norm squared and simplifying to get rid of the `Abs` will let it use derivatives.

Comment: P.S. Anyone else, including @indigoblue, should feel free to poach my ideas, if they are of any use, and write up an answer.  I won't have time today to pursue this further.

Comment: And something else that just came to me: Maybe `WhenEvent` can be used to give a good starting point for `FindMinimum` (or perhaps even to find the minimum).

Comment: Interesting, I've used WhenEvent before to change things such as velocities and angles, but how would I iterate through values of the parameter `p` in order to find the required Mars periapse intercept radius using WhenEvent? With regards to using `FindMinimum`, I used initial guesses where `t = TOF` and `p = pmin` by first getting `pmin` from `NMinimize` with `AccuracyGoal -> 10` and `PrecisionGoal -> 10` as a rough initial guess. Unfortunately I didn't notice any appreciable time difference with `AccuracyGoal -> 18` and `PrecisionGoal -> 18` when using these initial guesses in `FindMinimum`.

Comment: Forgive me if the suggestion does not make sense.  I haven't had the time to read the code carefully.  What I had in mind was the `NDSolve` approach presented in this answer, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58244/find-maximum-value-of-interpolation-function-obviously-wrong-result/58256#58256, but it sounds like it might not work here.

Comment: I had a go at using `WorkingPrecision -> 16` but this gave me the following error: `The precision of the differential equation ... is less than WorkingPrecision`. I'm not too sure how to fix this as the error example in the documentation doesn't seem to help unfortunately.

Comment: Try `SetPrecision[eqns, 16]`.

Comment: Using `SetPrecision[]` seemed to change something, but I'm not too sure what. I commented out `AccuracyGoal -> 10` and `PrecisionGoal -> 10` and wrapped `ParametricNDSolve` in `SetPrecision[ParametricNDSolve[...], 20]` since you mentioned that `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` are set to half of `WorkingPrecision` if not explicitly set. I then tried `SetPrecision[ParametricNDSolve[...], 40]` which seemed to make no further difference at all in terms of `NMinimize's` calculation time or actual `ParametricPlot` output. However, wouldn't this make `AccuracyGoal -> 20` and `PrecisionGoal -> 20`?

Comment: I think you want the form `ParametricNDSolve[SetPrecision[eqns, 20], vars, {t, t1, t2}, params, WorkingPrecision -> 20]` -- not `SetPrecision` on the outside.

Comment: @indigoblue What you are minimizing is `Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]`.  That you add a constant, such `(r[2] + 300000)`, has no impact whatsoever until the constant becomes so large that it dwarfs `Norm[...]`.  In fact, I have deleted that constant term with no change in result, as expected.

Comment: Ahhh I see, is there a way then to accurately target a periapse radius of 300km above Mars using NMinimize?

Comment: @indigoblue  I presume that you wish the trajectory to pass through a point 300km from Mars lying along a line from the Sun to Mars.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. Thinking about it a little bit more, it seems a more appropriate requirement would be for the spacecraft to pass through a point 300km from Mars _without_ subsequently crashing into it ;) More specifically I think this would require a radial line coming from Mars' centre to meet the spacecraft's velocity vector perpendicularly at its minimum approach point.

Comment: @indigoblue  I have the corrected version of `rm` and shall post it when I return in about two hours.  The trajectory to Mars is essentially unchanged, but the trajectory is very different at later times.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks bbgodfrey, looking forward to seeing it. Yup, it's the fact that the trajectory _after_ passing Mars is very different for different values of `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` that is getting me worried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I applied `Rationalize` to every decimal constant feeding into the computation of `Soln` and `rm`, and replaced `AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10` by `WorkingPrecision -> 60`.  The change in `rm` was negligible,

```
{3.69158*10^6, {t -> 2.10981*10^7, p -> 0.938622}}
```

before, and

```
{3.69179*10^6, {t -> 2.10981*10^7, p -> 0.938622}}
```

after these changes.  Consistent with the negligible change in  `rm`, there was no visible change to the second plot shown in the question.  I conclude, therefore, that the results obtained by the OP with `AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10` for the arrival of the trajectory **at Mars orbit** are correct.

For completeness, I should note that the `WorkingPrecision -> 60` computation took just over 24 minutes to complete.  Of course, I am not suggesting that such a high working precision should be used in general, only that doing so validates results with smaller `WorkingPrecision`.  For instance, `WorkingPrecision -> 15` produces the result

```
{3.69097*10^6, {t -> 2.10981*10^7, p -> 0.938622}}
```

in just over two minutes.  The code in the question takes only about five seconds and produces the same result **up to the point of arriving at Mars**.

**Details of Code Modifications**

In answer to a comment below, the specific changes I made to the code are as follows (only changed lines shown):

```
G = Rationalize[6.672]*10^-11;
ms = Rationalize[1.988544]*10^30 ;(*Mass of Sun*)
me = Rationalize[5.97219]*10^24 ;(*Mass of Earth*)
mm = Rationalize[6.4185]*10^23 ;(*Mass of Mars*)
r[0] = Rationalize[6.963]*10^8 ;(*Mean radius of Sun*) 
r[1] = Rationalize[6.37101] *10^6;(*Mean radius of Earth*) 
r[2] = Rationalize[3.3899]*10^6 ;(*Mean radius of Mars*)
pe = 149597870700 {Rationalize[4.416639858432274*10^-1, 0], 
    Rationalize[8.798967504313304*10^-1, 0]} ;
pm = 149597870700 {Rationalize[-8.159382724017646*10^-1, 0], 
    Rationalize[1.414986880765974*10^0, 0]};
ve = 149597870700/86400 {-Rationalize[1.563974110293042*10^-2, 0], 
    Rationalize[7.690252775639107*10^-3, 0]};
vm = 149597870700/
    86400 {-Rationalize[1.160326991502370*10^-2, 0], -Rationalize[
      5.778933879736245*10^-3, 0]} ;
vinf = Norm[{-Rationalize[29134.32], Rationalize[15779.21]} - ve];
e = Rationalize[6.37526];

rm = NMinimize[{(Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], 
          ysc[t][p]}] + (r[2] + 300000)) /. Soln, 
    TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 8/10 < p < 1}, {t, p}, 
   Method -> "NelderMead"] // AbsoluteTiming
rm = rm // Last;
```

Note that, for instance, `G = Rationalize[6.672*10^-11]` does not work for reasons explained in the documentation.  Instead, one must use `G = Rationalize[6.672*10^-11, 0]` or `G = Rationalize[6.672]*10^-11`.  If any of the decimal constants does not `Rationalize`, `ParametricNDSolve` fails with the error,

```
ParametricNDSolve::precw: The precision of the differential equation ... is less than WorkingPrecision (15.`). >>
```

**Revised rm Definition**

In response to the **Edit** in the question and associated comments above, `rm` has been revised so that the distance of closest approach of the trajectory to the surface of Mars is 300 km (i.e., `r[2] + 300000` from the center of Mars).  At the point of closest approach, the normal to the trajectory passes through the center of Mars.  Thus,

```
rm = NMinimize[{Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} + {ysc'[t][p], -xsc'[t][p]} (r[2] + 300000)/
  Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}] - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]  /. Soln, 
  TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 8/10 < p < 1}, {t, p}, Method -> "NelderMead"]
```

In addition, `xsc'[t]` and `ysc'[t]` must be included in the list of dependent variables in `ParametricNDSolve`.  These changes yield a computed value of `rm` of

```
{0.00334441, {t -> 2.10977*10^7, p -> 0.938655}}
```

The first number is the suitably small residual distance, and `t` and `p` are essentially unchanged from results given earlier in this answer.  Likewise, the corresponding trajectory plot from Earth to Mars is virtually unchanged from the second figure in the question.  However, the trajectory past Mars is different from the third and fourth plots in the question, because the deflection of the trajectory by the gravitational field of Mars is less.

[image]

**Improved, Revised rm Computation**

As noted by the OP in various comments, the computation described immediately above often yields a distance of closest approach accurate to only of order 10%.  A more accurate computational approach is the following.  Add to the options for `ParametricNDSolve` in the original code,

```
InterpolationOrder -> 6
```

in order to provide smoother interpolation of the numerical results.  Then, define

```
g[t0_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := Module[{tem = 
    Norm[{xsc[t][p] - xm[t][p], ysc[t][p] - ym[t][p]}] /. Soln}, tem /. t -> t0];
h[t0_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := Module[{tem = {xsc[t][p] - xm[t][p], 
    ysc[t][p] - ym[t][p]}.{xsc'[t][p] - xm'[t][p], ysc'[t][p] - ym'[t][p]}/
    (Norm[{xsc[t][p] - xm[t][p], ysc[t][p] - ym[t][p]}] 
    Norm[{xsc'[t][p] - xm'[t][p], ysc'[t][p] - ym'[t][p]}]) /. Soln}, tem /. t -> t0];
h1[t0_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := Module[{tem = (ysc[t][p] - ym[t][p]) /. Soln}, 
    tem /. t -> t0];
```

The definition of `g` is taken from [91171](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91171/nminimize-constraints-on-interpolating-functions/91512#91512), and the other functions patterned after it.  `h` is the dot product of the tangent of the trajectory and a line from Mars to the corresponding point on the trajectory.  When `h` vanishes, the line represents the distance of closest approach.  `h1` is simply the signed distance in `y` between the trajectory and Mars.  `h1 < 0` indicates that the trajectory passes Mars on the Sun-ward side.  Note that `xm'` and `ym'` should be added to the list of dependent variables in `ParametricNDSolve` to improve the accuracy of `h`.  With these definitions, the new `rm` expression is

```
rm = NMinimize[{Abs[g[t, p] - 10000000], h1[t, p] < 0, h[t, p] == 0}, 
    {{t, TOF - 10 (86400), TOF + 10 (86400)}, {p, 0.9, 1}}, 
    Method -> "NelderMead", MaxIterations -> 200, PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

(The OP seeks a distance of closest approach of `10000000`.)  Executing the code for `rm` yields

```
(* {0.0166112, {t -> 2.1097*10^7, p -> 0.938693}} *)
```

but with the warning,

```
NMinimize::nosat: Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001`: {-h[t,p]==0}. >>
```

and, indeed, `h[rm[[2, 1, 2]], rm[[2, 2, 2]]]` evaluates to `0.0970054`, which is not particularly good. Nonetheless, the corresponding distance of closest approach,

```
NMinimize[Norm[{xsc[t][p] - xm[t][p], ysc[t][p] - ym[t][p]} /. Soln /. 
    rm[[2, 2]]], {t, TOF - 10 (86400), TOF + 10 (86400)}]
(* {9.9412*10^6, {t -> 2.10968*10^7}} *)
```

which is accurate to better than 1%.  (When accuracy is less good,

```
FindRoot[{g[t, p] == 10000000, h[t, p] == 0}, {{t, rmc[[2, 1, 2]]}, {p, rmc[[2, 2, 2]]}}]
```

sometimes helps.  Here, it issues the `FindRoot::lstol:` warning.)

Below is a plot of the trajectory near Mars, together with a circle centered on Mars with radius of `10000000`.

```
Show[With[{pmin = 0.938693}, ParametricPlot[{xsc[t][pmin] - xm[t][pmin], 
    ysc[t][pmin] - ym[t][pmin]} /. Soln , {t, TOF - 10 (86400), 
    TOF + 10 (86400)}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{-15000000, 15000000}, {-15000000, 15000000}}]], 
    Graphics[{Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, 10000000]}]]
```

[image]

From the preceding discussion, one might expect that increasing `WorkingPrecision` throughout would yield better final results, but it does not for the cases I have tried.  It also is excruciatingly slow.

**Simpler, Often More Accurate Approach**

If a reasonable initial guess is available for `t` and `p` (for instance, from plots in the answers to [91171](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91171/nminimize-constraints-on-interpolating-functions/91512#91512)), then FindRoot sometimes but not always works very well, despite the warning message mentioned above.

```
fr = FindRoot[{g[t, p] == 10000000, h[t, p] == 0}, {{t, 2.1099 10^7}, {p, .93865}}]
(g[t, p] /. fr) - 10000000
h[t, p] /. fr
NMinimize[Norm[{xsc[t][p] - xm[t][p], ysc[t][p] - ym[t][p]} /. Soln /. fr],
    {t, TOF - 10 (86400), TOF + 10 (86400)}]

(* {t -> 2.10968*10^7, p -> 0.938693}
   -0.00279256
   3.25049*10^-7
   {1.*10^7, {t -> 2.10968*10^7}} *)
```

Incidentally, choosing as an initial guess `p -> 0.93855` yields the other intersection, on the far side of Mars.

Comment: This is of course one of the standard ways to verify that your low-precision result is correct.

Comment: @J. M.  Thanks, that was my intent. Had the OP's procedure not been substantiated, I would have tried to improve upon it.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, how did you get `WorkingPrecision` to work as a `ParametricNDSolve` option without getting errors? I'd love to test this myself as well.

Comment: @indigoblue  Please see the Addendum to my answer.

Comment: @indigo, in short, bb here replaced all your inexact constants with exact versions before cranking up the appropriate settings. `SetPrecision[x, ∞]` would have worked equally well here.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, the new code you produced seems to work very well in targeting a 300km Mars periapse radius. Thank you! However, I'm trying to see what equation you used inside NMinimize (`Norm[{xm[t][p], 
   ym[t][p]} + {ysc'[t][p], -xsc'[t][p]} (r[2] + 300000)/
    Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}] - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]` to get this, and am struggling a little to decipher the code. Do you think you could give the equation in Latex form?

Comment: @indigoblue  At the point of closest approach, the normal to the trajectory passes through the center of Mars.  It is along this normal that the distance, `(r[2] + 300000)` should be measured.  Since the normalized tangent vector of the trajectory is `{xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}/Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}] `, the normalized perpendicular vector is `{ysc'[t][p], -xsc'[t][p]}/ Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}] `.  Multiply this by the desired distance, above, to obtain the correction to the distance to be minimized.  Hope this helps.  By the way, please Accept the answer, if it meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation bbgodfrey, that clears things up nicely :). I do have one more question though: I've noticed that, although we aim for a 300km Mars periapse radius, `NMinimize` doesn't seem to be able to get such an accurate answer (I get a peripase of about 220km using a 300km periapse aim point). I could just adjust the aim point until the output gives me 300km, but I feel that would be defeating the point of using the optimization in the first place. Do you possibly know why `NMinimize` is unable to give a more accurate answer?

Comment: @indigoblue  With `WorkingPrecision -> 15`, I get a residual error `rm[[1]] = 0.00377987`, which is quite good, I believe.  Are you using the code modifications listed in my answer, and no other changes, apart from replacing ` AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10` by `WorkingPrecision -> 15`?

Comment: I get the following results: `{34.3609, {t -> 2.10977*10^7, p -> 0.938655}}`. I assume that my residual error of `34.3609` is in metres? If so then it seems like the answer should be correct. However, I also used the following piece of code `rmin = NMinimize[
 Join[Norm[{xm[t], ym[t]} - {xsc[t], ysc[t]}] /. 
    Soln, {TOF - 10 (86400) <= t <= TOF + 10 (86400)}], t]` which, if it works correctly, should provide another way of seeing what the minimum distance was. Maybe there is an error here

Comment: The code in your last comment generates errors, probably because `p` is not specified, and `Join` may be inappropriate here.  And, yes, the residual error is in meters.

Comment: Oh my apologies, this code should work: `rmin = NMinimize[{Norm[{xm[t][pmin], ym[t][pmin]} - {xsc[t][pmin], 
       ysc[t][pmin]}] /. Soln, 
   TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400)}, t, 
  Method -> "NelderMead"]`, I've used the above piece of code after the original NMinimize that searches both `t` and `p`; however, I've set `p` constant (`pmin`) by giving it the value of `p` found in the first NMinimize, and asked this new NMinimize to give me the closest approach radius and at what time it occurs. I then used `rmin[[2]][[1]] - r[2]`

Comment: Going back to constraints, would it not be possible to do something like the following: `rm = NMinimize[{Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], 
       ysc[t][p]}] /. Soln, 
   Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /. 
    Soln >= r[2] + 300000, 
   TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 8/10 < p < 14/10}, {t, 
   p}, Method -> "NelderMead"]`, where `Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /. 
 Soln >= r[2] + 300000` is added as another constraint. I've tried this exact piece of code, but it seems I can't get the syntax correct.

Comment: After testing your improved code for more practical rendezvous radii closer than `10000000` I see that unfortunately the optimization "breaks" once again, even with your improved version. Either way, you more than deserve to have your above answer accepted as you've helped me immensely. Unfortunately I guess this is just a difficult optimization problem that Mathematica stuggles to deal with :/

Comment: @indigoblue  With `fr = FindRoot[{g[t, p] == 1000000, h[t, p] == 0}, {{t, 2.1098 10^7}, {p, .93864}}]`, I obtain `{t -> 2.10978*10^7, p -> 0.938637}`.  What approach distance are you seeking?  Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: I'm hoping to get a rendezvous radius of 300km above Mars' surface. That is, `r[2]+300000`.

Comment: @indigoblue  With the new radius but otherwise the same input as before, `fr = FindRoot[{g[t, p] == r[2] + 300000, h[t, p] == 0}, {{t, 2.1098 10^7}, {p, .93864}}]`, I obtain `{t -> 2.1097566447315533*^7, p -> 0.938655699695824}`.  Incidentally, I looked in more detail yesterday at the actual solution produced by `ParametricNDSolve`,  which typically is only about `70` points.  However, they appear to be well placed in `t`, so I trust the final answers.

Comment: Brilliant bbgodfrey! I was worried that the FindRoot approach would be too much "trial and error", but feeding the `t` and `p` results from `rm = NMinimize[{Abs[g[t, p] - r[2] - 10000000], h1[t, p] < 0, 
   h[t, p] == 0}, {{t, TOF - 10 (86400), TOF + 10 (86400)}, {p, 0.9, 
    1}}, Method -> "NelderMead", MaxIterations -> 200, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 10]` (with its aiming radius of `10000000`) was enough to get a very accurate result of `300km` above Mars upon rendezvous.

Comment: As an aside (and I'm very sorry to continue on like this), why does FindRoot work where the other forms of optimization fail so horribly? Unfortunately I know next to nothing about mathematical optimization, and if I run into a similar problem in the future, I'd like to be able to know why they don't/do work. Thanks again!

Comment: @indigoblue  In my mind, the question is not, why does `NMinimize` do poorly rather than why `FindRoot` does well.  Both give good results for `g[t, p] == r[2] + 300000`, but only `FindRoot` also gives a good result for `h[t, p] == 0`.  Ultimately, both must vary `t` and `p` in order to satisfy both equalities, and `FindRoot` apparently is better optimized to obtain high accuracy, given a good starting guess.  `NMinimize` on the other hand may be optimized for obtaining reasonable answers without an initial guess.   The bottom line is, I simply do not know.  Sorry.