# NMinimize Constraints on Interpolating Functions

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, interpolation, constraint

I have the following piece of code and am trying to use `NMinimize` **(the last line in the following chunk of code)** to minimize `Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]` with the constraint that this value must be greater than, say, `10000000`. That is, `Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]>10000000`:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
(*Gravitational Constant*)
G = 6.672*10^-11;
(*Simulation running time, in seconds (1 day = 86400 seconds)*)
tmax = (1000) (86400);
(*Spacecraft time-of-flight between Earth and Mars, in seconds (1 day = 86400 seconds)*)
TOF = (254) (86400);
(*Mass of Sun, Earth, Mars (from JPL's Horizons ephemeris), in kilograms*)
ms = 1.988544*10^30 ;(*Mass of Sun*)
me = 5.97219*10^24 ;(*Mass of Earth*)
mm = 6.4185*10^23 ;(*Mass of Mars*)
(*Planetary radii of Sun, Earth and Mars (from JPL's Horizons ephemeris), in metres*)
r[0] = 6.963*10^8 ;(*Mean radius of Sun*) 
r[1] = 6.37101 *10^6;(*Mean radius of Earth*) 
r[2] = 3.3899*10^6 ;(*Mean radius of Mars*)
(*Heliocentric positions of Earth and Mars (from JPL's Horizons ephemeris) on 26 November 2011, in metres*)
pe = 149597870700 {4.416639858432274*10^-1, 8.798967504313304*10^-1} ;
pm = 149597870700 {-8.159382724017646*10^-1, 1.414986880765974*10^0};
(*Heliocentric velocities of Earth and Mars (from JPL's Horizons ephemeris) on 26 November 2011, in metres*)
ve = 149597870700/86400 {-1.563974110293042*10^-2, 7.690252775639107*10^-3};
vm = 149597870700/86400 {-1.160326991502370*10^-2, -5.778933879736245*10^-3} ;
(*Hyperbolic excess velocity, in metres per second. Difference between spacecraft's Heliocentric velocity vLambert[1] and Earth's Heliocentric velocity ve*)
vinf = Norm[{-29134.32, 15779.21} - ve];
(*Earth orbital radius of departure hyperbola, in metres*)
rp = (r[1] + 300000);
(*Earth ejection angle, in radians*)
e = 6.37526;

(*Interplanetary transfer trajectory model*)
(*Models the motion of Earth (xe, ye), Mars (xm, ym) and spacecraft (xsc, ysc) in a Cartesian coordinate system*)
Soln = ParametricNDSolve[{
   xe''[t] == -((G ms xe[t])/(xe[t]^2 + ye[t]^2)^(3/2)),
   ye''[t] == -((G ms ye[t])/(xe[t]^2 + ye[t]^2)^(3/2)),
   xm''[t] == -((G ms xm[t])/(xm[t]^2 + ym[t]^2)^(3/2)),
   ym''[t] == -((G ms ym[t])/(xm[t]^2 + ym[t]^2)^(3/2)),
   xsc''[t] == -((G ms xsc[t])/(xsc[t]^2 + ysc[t]^2)^(3/2)) - (G me (xsc[t] - xe[t]))/((xsc[t] - xe[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ye[t])^2)^(3/2) - (G mm (xsc[t] - xm[t]))/((xsc[t] - xm[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ym[t])^2)^(3/2),
   ysc''[t] == -((G ms ysc[t])/(xsc[t]^2 + ysc[t]^2)^(3/2)) - (G me (ysc[t] - ye[t]))/((xsc[t] - xe[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ye[t])^2)^(3/2) - (G mm (ysc[t] - ym[t]))/((xsc[t] - xm[t])^2 + (ysc[t] - ym[t])^2)^(3/2),

   xe[0] == pe[[1]], ye[0] == pe[[2]], xm[0] == pm[[1]], 
   ym[0] == pm[[2]], xsc[0] == pe[[1]] + (r[1] + 300000) Cos[e p], 
   ysc[0] == pe[[2]] + (r[1] + 300000) Sin[e p], xe'[0] == ve[[1]], 
   ye'[0] == ve[[2]], xm'[0] == vm[[1]], ym'[0] == vm[[2]], 
   xsc'[0] == ve[[1]] - Sqrt[vinf^2 + (2 G me)/rp] Sin[e p], 
   ysc'[0] == ve[[2]] + Sqrt[vinf^2 + (2 G me)/rp] Cos[e p]}, {xe[t], 
   ye[t], xm[t], ym[t], xsc[t], ysc[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, {p}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> 10000000]

(*Finding value for parameter p that will fix the Earth ejection angle and produce the desired orbital radius upon Mars intercept*)
(*Constrained spacecraft to target an orbit of 300km above Mars*)
(*Constrained time search to be 10 days before and 10 days after "ideal" intercept time TOF*)
rm = NMinimize[{Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /. Soln, TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 0.8 < p < 1}, {t, p}, Method -> "NelderMead"]
```

I thought that using may have worked:

```
rm = NMinimize[{
       Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /. Soln,
       Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] > 10000000 /. Soln,
       TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 0.8 < p < 1},
      {t, p}, Method -> "NelderMead"
     ]
```

However, I seem to be getting syntax errors when adding in

`Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] > 10000000 /. Soln`

which I think is due to the fact that I'm not using `/.Soln` correctly.

Would anyone know how I can apply the desired constraint without getting such errors? Thanks very much.

---

**EDIT:**

Since the above bit of code it quite unwieldy, I've added a simpler example showing what I'd like to do. Suppose we have the following numerical output of a differential equation in the form of an interpolating function:

```
DE = Flatten[NDSolve[{u''[t] + u[t] == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 5}]]
Plot[u[t] /. DE, {t, 0, 5}]
```

And lets say I want to minimize the function `u[t]` on the interval `0<t<3`, but also want `u[t]>0.5`. Then, using `/.DE` to apply the values of the interpolating function `DE` to `u[t]` I'd have

```
NMinimize[{u[t] /. DE, u[t] > 0.5 /. DE, 0 < t < 3}, t]
```

which gives me `{0.5, {t -> 2.61799}}`.

[image]

I'm trying to do something very similar to this, in the original code I posted. Except instead of minimizing `u[t]`, I'm minimizing `Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]` and instead of requiring that `u[t]>0.5`, I would like `Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] > 1000000`. The only problem is that, following the same syntax procedures as I did on the simple example, I seem to be getting errors on the original code when trying to apply the additional constraint (the code gives no errors, however, without the additional constraint applied).

Comment: Your code is too large and unwieldy. Please do some troubleshooting yourself first, to try and isolate the cause of your trouble, and then post a minimal example reproducing your problem.

Comment: The issue is in the very last line of the code and everything above it can essentially be ignored. I put the rest of the code in so that someone running it would get results out.

Comment: The cause of the trouble is in NMinimize. I'd like to put an additional constraint where `Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]>10000000`, but cannot figure out how to do this since I get syntax errors. Every other piece of the code is working as planned

Comment: So I ran your complex code chunk, and it runs without errors; the output is `{1768.23, {t -> 2.10981*10^7, p -> 0.938622}}`. I didn't get any syntax errors etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look MarcoB. Yup, the code currently runs without any errors, but I'm trying to add an additional constraint to NMinimize where `Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]>10000000` using the following `rm = NMinimize[{Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /. Soln, Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]>10000000/.Soln, TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 0.8 < p < 1}, {t, p}, Method -> "NelderMead"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by the OP, adding the constraint,

```
Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] > 10000000 /. Soln
```

triggers error messages, probably because `p` typically must be given a numerical value before `t` is given one in expressions such as `xm[t][p]`.  See the documentation for `ParametricFunction`.  This can be accomplished by defining

```
g[t0_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := Module[{tem = 
    Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /. Soln}, tem /. t -> t0]
```

in which case the constrained expression, renamed `rmc`, becomes

```
rmc = NMinimize[{g[t, p], g[t, p] > 10000000, TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) 
    && 0.8 < p < 1}, {t, p}, Method -> "NelderMead"]
(* {1.*10^7, {t -> 2.10972*10^7, p -> 0.938692}} *)
```

although with the inconsequential warning,

```
NMinimize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. >>
```

More insight can be obtained by plotting the curve in `t - p` space for which `g[t, p] == 10000000`, along with the points defined by `rm` and `rmc`.

```
Show[ContourPlot[g[t, p], {t, TOF - 9.85 (86400), TOF - 9.75 (86400)}, 
       {p, .9385, .9387}, FrameLabel -> {t, p}, Contours -> {10000000}, 
       ContourShading -> {White, Green}], 
     Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{rm[[2, 1, 2]], rm[[2, 2, 2]]}], Blue, 
       Point[{rmc[[2, 1, 2]], rmc[[2, 2, 2]]}]}]]
```

[image]

The `White` region corresponds to `Norm[...] < 10000000`, which is excluded by the added constraint.  The value of `rmc` (`Blue`) corresponds to but one point on a closed curve, `Norm[...] == 10000000`, and the value of `rm` (`Red`) to the true minimum computed in the question.

Comment: Thanks bbgodfrey, I see that this did not work as I had hoped. I thought that, if I wanted to find the value of `p` that would minimize the distance between the spacecraft and Mars, but also added an additional constraint so that the spacecraft would not go below a certain value (in this case 10000000), `NMinimize` would find the global minimum to be the spacecraft's periapse radius relative to Mars and would not let this periapse radius go below 10000000. Would the "minimum of all minimums" for the above set of minimums be the periapse radius?

Comment: @indigoblue  To obtain what you describe in your last comment, use `rm = NMinimize[{Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} + {ysc'[t][p], -xsc'[t][p]} (r[2] + 10000000)/Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}] - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}]  /. Soln, 
  TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 8/10 < p < 1}, {t, p}, Method -> "NelderMead"]`.  The calculation described in the question above instead yields all values of `p` for which the trajectory passes at `10000000` or closer to Mars, and the corresponding `t`s at which the distance is`10000000`, one while approaching and the other while departing..

Comment: @indigoblue  Nonetheless, the plot in my answer above does give the values of `p` and `t` for which the closest approach of the trajectory is `10000000`.  They are the maximum and minimum `p` values on the curve, and the corresponding `t` values.  One corresponds to passing Mars on the inside of its orbit, and the other on the outside.

Comment: Do you possibly have a link to the mathematics used for the `{ysc'[t][p], -xsc'[t][p]} (r[2] + 10000000)/Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}]` part? I see you use a unit vector formulation, but don't fully understand why `{ysc'[t][p], -xsc'[t][p]}` makes the spacecraft trajectory normal to a radial vector emanating from Mars' centre.

Comment: @indigoblue  I do not have a reference.  Instead, I derived the expression by noting that a vector from the center of Mars to the trajectory must be perpendicular to the trajectory at the point of closest approach.  See also the discussion in my answer to your earlier [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88061/using-parametricndsolve-and-nminimize-to-find-accurate-interplanetary-trajectory/88079#88079).

Comment: In my previous post you linked me to, when you said "since the normalized tangent vector of the trajectory is `{xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}/Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}]` , the normalized perpendicular vector is `{ysc'[t][p], -xsc'[t][p]}/ Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}]`" did you actually mean `{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}/Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}]` is the normalized tangent vector?

Comment: @indigoblue  Yes, I did.  Sorry.

Comment: No problem, and thank you, it makes sense now. It's just taking the "inverse reciprocal" :)

Comment: Unfortunately the story hasn't seemed to have finished :/. I see that the optimization process seems to be getting stuck on a local minimum. If I use `rm = NMinimize[{Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], 
       ysc[t][p]} + {ysc'[t][p], -xsc'[t][p]} (10000000)/
        Norm[{xsc'[t][p], ysc'[t][p]}]] /. Soln, 
   TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 8/10 < p < 1}, {t, p}, 
  Method -> "NelderMead"]` I get a value of `9.99999*10^6` at `t=2.10979*10^7`. However, the actual minimum is `8.9987*10^6` and occurs at `t=2.10969*10^7`.

Comment: I found this using `dr = Table[
   Norm[{xm[t][pmin], ym[t][pmin]} - {xsc[t][pmin], ysc[t][pmin]}] /. 
    Soln, {t, TOF - 10 (86400), TOF + 10 (86400), 10}];` and `mindr = Min[dr]`. I've tried various other `NMinimize` methods with varying options, but still can't seem to "hit" the glolbal min.

Comment: @indigoblue  The calculation in your first recent comment correctly minimizes the difference between the distance of closest approach of the trajectory and `10000000`.  The calculation in your second recent comment gives the distance of closest approach for the undefined quantity `pmin` (probably about `pmin -> .9386875`).  With `p -> 0.938622`, you could put the trajectory through the center of Mars.  But your goal, I believe is to put the distance of closest approach at `10000000`, and  your first comment accomplishes that.

Comment: Very sorry about that, yes, `pmin=0.9386875` and is taken from `rm`. However what I'm trying to do with the second comment is actually measure (not minimize) the distance between Mars and the spacecraft, when using `pmin`, by simply finding the Euclidean norm for various points along the spacecraft's trajectory as it approaches Mars. Using this, I see that the spacecraft reaches it's closest point to Mars at time `t=2.10969*10^7` with a radial distance `r=8.9987*10^6` from Mars, and not at time `t=2.10979*10^7` with a radial distance of `r=9.99999*10^6` as the `NMinimize` gives.

Comment: What I had hoped was that when I used the value of `pmin`, the spacecraft would reach the given value of `r=9.99999*10^6` and get no closer, but unfortunately it does get closer, thus violating the constraint.

Comment: @indigoblue  I now have a better understanding of your issue, which is valid.  Please see [88061](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88061/using-parametricndsolve-and-nminimize-to-find-accurate-interplanetary-trajectory) for an improved `rm`.

Answer (score 3):

As the Norm is positive, you don't really need the constraint to determine one minimum for `p` and `t`:

```
nm = NMinimize[{
            (Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] - 10^7)^2 /. Soln,
             TOF - 10 (86400) < t < TOF + 10 (86400) && 0.8 < p < 1}, {t, p}, 
             Method -> "NelderMead"]

(* {0.000155262, {t -> 2.10956*10^7, p -> 0.938678}} *)
```

Testing;

```
ContourPlot[ Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /. Soln,
             {t, TOF - 9.85 (86400), TOF - 9.75 (86400)}, {p, .9385, .9387},
             Contours -> {10^7},
             Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{t, p} /. nm[[2]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may find the parametric interpolation for the whole minimal contour:

```
cp = ContourPlot[
  Norm[{xm[t][p], ym[t][p]} - {xsc[t][p], ysc[t][p]}] /. Soln,
  {t, TOF - 9.85 (86400), TOF - 9.75 (86400)}, {p, .9385, .9387},
  Contours -> {10^7}, ContourShading -> False, Frame -> False];

f = Interpolation /@ Transpose@First[Cases[cp // Normal, Line[x__] :> x, Infinity]]

ParametricPlot[Through[f[t]], {t, 1, 327}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]