# Problem in finding the actual minimum of a rapidly varying function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have been facing the problem of finding the true minimum of a rapidly varying functions. The commands like `FindMinimum` and `NMinimize` often lead to the minimum value which is the global minimum for that function. I try to present an example here:

```
y[x_] = Sin[10 x^2] + 5 Cos[20 x];
```

When I plot this function say in region {x,0,5}, I can see the minima which are lower in value than returned by the `FindMinimum` and `NMinimize` commands. Can anyone help to figure out what is going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the options to either `NMinimize` or `FindMinimum`? Take a look at the [tutorial here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html). For example, try `NMinimize[Sin[10 x^2] + 5 Cos[20 x], {x}, 
 Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 500}]`.

Comment: I notice you haven't accepted any answers yet to any of your questions.  It's not much, but it's the way to show gratitude on the site to those who have given you help voluntarily, without charge or recompense, and to help other visitors find answers to their questions. If there are answers that solve your problems, please select the one that in your opinion is the best.

Comment: Oh I am sorry Sir. The answers have really helped me a lot.

Comment: But could you please tell me what do you mean by accepting the answer? I would definitely like to thank all the people who have helped me on this site in one or the other ways.

Comment: @Jee See my first comment: click the checkmark sign.  There's a link that explains it, if you have trouble finding the sign to click.

Answer (score 6):

`MinimalBy` is an easy way.

```
y[x_] = Sin[10 x^2] + 5 Cos[20 x];
d = Table[{x, y[x]}, {x, 1, 5, 0.0001}];
{X, Y} = First@MinimalBy[d, Last]

{1.7278, -5.99996}
```

**Edit**

For a better overview one can do the same with a plot.

```
plot = Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 500];
```

Determine the plot points.

```
p1 = Join @@ Cases[Normal@plot, Line[x1__] :> x1, Infinity];
{X, Y} = First@MinimalBy[p1, Last]
{1.72783, -5.99996}

Length@p1
**8635**
```

**Edit 2**

```
plt = Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 5}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {y'[#] &}, PlotPoints -> 500];
p2 = Cases[Normal[plt], Point[pt_] :> pt, Infinity];
{X, Y} = First@MinimalBy[p2, Last]
{1.72776, -5.99996}

Length@p2
**61**
```

To compare the number of points `p1` and `p2`, I chose the same number of plot points. @J.M. 's hint to add `Mesh->{{0}},MeshFunctions->{y'[#]&}` in the plot greatly reduces the number of points in `p2`.

```
Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 5}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {y'[#] &}, 
 MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium], Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Large, Point@{X, Y}}]
```

[image]

Thanks to @J.M. for pointing this out!

Comment: Since you're plotting anyway, use `MeshFunctions`: `f[x_] := Sin[10 x^2] + 5 Cos[20 x]; plt = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {f'[#] &}, PlotPoints -> 75]; MinimalBy[Cases[Normal[plt], Point[pt_] :> pt, Infinity], Last]`.

Comment: @ J. M. Hmm.., I want to get the red point for a visually test having taken the minimal point.

Comment: @ J. M. Why to add `Mesh->{{0}},MeshFunctions->{f'[#]&}` in the plot only to replace `Line[x1__] :> x1` with `Point[pt_] :> pt` ? Of course I have to add `Join@@` at the beginning, but thats all.

Comment: Because that extracts only the extrema of the function as opposed to all the points.

Comment: @ J. M. I know `MeshFunctions->{f'[#]&` . Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @rewi +1 elegant solution

Answer (score 5):

*Too long for a comment.*

---

```
y[x_] = Sin[10 x^2] + 5 Cos[20 x];
d = Table[{x, y[x]}, {x, 1, 5, 0.0001}];

min = Min@d[[All, 2]]
```

> -5.99996

```
pos = Position[d, min]
```

> {{7279, 2}}

```
d[[pos[[1, 1]]]]
```

> {1.7278, -5.99996}

(In an instant.)

---

On the other hand:

```
NMinimize[{y[x], 5 > x > 0}, x]
```

> {-5.99954, {x -> 4.87009}}

```
NMinimize[{Sin[10 x^2] + 5 Cos[20 x], 5 > x > 0}, {x}, 
 Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 500}]
```

> {-5.99954, {x -> 4.87009}}

---

Also

```
fmin = Quiet@
    Table[FindMinimum[{y[x], 5 > x > 0}, {x, i}], {i, 0, 5, 
      0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.29685, Null}

```
fmin[[Position[fmin, Min@fmin[[All, 1]]][[1, 1]]]]
```

> {-5.99997, {x -> 1.72776}}

so the first method is fastest.

Answer (score 4):

On such a univariate function, a direct calculus approach is feasible:

```
With[{f = Sin[10 x^2] + 5 Cos[20 x]},
 Min[f /. NSolve[{D[f, x], 0 <= x <= 5}, x]]
 ]
(*  -5.99997  *)
```

The numerical minimizers tend to involve some sort of search method, and generally only return the least local minimum found.  From the "Details" of [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html):

> - If `f` and `cons` are linear, `NMinimize` can always find global minima, over both real and integer values.
> - Otherwise, `NMinimize` may sometimes find only a local minimum.

Comment: It is also possible to use `Solve[D[f,x]==0 && 0<=x<=5, x]` to get "exact" results.

Answer (score 4):

Using `FindRoot[]` to find the zeros of the first derivative of the function in a given interval `{a,b}` with a certain granularity of inspection `d` we arrive at:

```
y[x_] = Sin[10 x^2] + 5 Cos[20 x];

a = -1; (* lower endpoint of search interval *)
b = 3; (* upper endpoint of search interval *)
d = 0.01; (* sampling interval *)
psize = 0.015; (* point size of extrema in plot *)
data = {#, y[#]} & /@ 
  Union[Flatten[
    Table[x /. FindRoot[y'[x] == 0, {x, {z}}], {z, a, b, d}] // Chop],
    SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < d/2 &)];
datamax = Select[data, #[[2]] > 0 &]; 
datamin = Select[data, #[[2]] < 0 &];

Plot[y[x], {x, a, b}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize -> psize, {Black, Point /@ datamax}, {Red, 
    Point /@ datamin}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One view of the problem focuses on the issue of getting a sample point in the one valley where the absolute minimum lies.  If you know something about the minimum width of the valleys of your objective function(s), then one can sample at regular intervals of less than this width.  To write a generic solver, the minimum width would be unknown. In this answer, I will present an approach that should work on a fairly smooth objective function.

The method is based on making a Chebyshev approximation to the function. When the approximation is fairly good, there will usually be several sample points per oscillation, assuming the amplitude of the oscillations are fairly large. The function values at the sample points are computed Chebyshev approximation. These can be used to locate valleys using `PeakDetect[-values]`. Finally `FindMinimum` is used to polish the minima, and the ones with the least function value are returned.  (It's set up to return multiple solutions, if the absolute minimum occurs at several locations. It's possible that some locations are missed in some cases.)

#### Example uses

OP's example:

```
min1 = chebMinimize[Sin[10 x^2] + 5 Cos[20 x], {x, 0, 5}]  // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.020218,  {-5.99997, {{x -> 1.72776}}} }  *)
```

Minima at end points:

```
chebMinimize[-x^2, {x, -1, 1}]
(*  {-1., {{x -> 1.}, {x -> -1.}}}  *)
```

Example with almost 10000 local minima:

```
obj = Sin[50000 x + 1]/1000 + Sin[200 Cos[Pi x/2]^8 x];
min1 = chebMinimize[obj, {x, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20]  // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {4.79622,  {-1.001, {{x -> -0.605373}}} }  *)
```

The underlying Chebyshev approximation is much faster than 10000 `FindMinima[]` calls. One can limit the number of local minima and speed things up:

```
min1 = chebMinimize[obj, {x, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20, "MaxMinima" -> 100]  //
  AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.08998,  {-1.001, {{x -> -0.605373}}} }  *)
```

The least local minima (in the discrete list of values of `obj` at the sample points) are chosen, but it's possible to undersample. The success depends on where the sample points fall with respect to the absolute minimum. Note that the result below, while close, is not quite right.

```
min2 = chebMinimize[obj, {x, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20, "MaxMinima" -> 10]  //
  AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.046868,  {-1.001, {{x -> -0.340726}}} }  *)

min1[[2, 1]] - min2[[2, 1]]
(*  -1.07694*10^-7  *)
```

#### Code dump

There are two helper functions. The function `` cheb`approx[] `` computes a Chebyshev series approximation to a function `f` over an interval `{x, a, b}`; it returns the sample points/abscissae and function values in the form `{xvals, fvals}`. The function `` cheb`minpos[] `` returns the positions of the local minima in a list of values.

There is an irrelevant data structure `` cheb`data `` that I've been using to inspect the workings of the algorithm. For example, `` Length@cheb`data["Y"] `` will give the number of function values, and `` Length@cheb`data["M"] `` gives the number of local minima. (It gets overwritten with every call to `chebMinimize[]`.)

```
ClearAll[chebMinimize];
Options[chebMinimize] = {MinRecursion -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
   Tolerance -> 1.*^-8, 
   "SuppressMessages" :> {FindMinimum::lstol, FindMinimum::reged}, 
   "MaxMinima" -> Infinity};
chebMinimize::ncv = 
  "chebMinimize failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after `1` \
recursive bisections of {`2`, `3`}. chebMinimize obtained `4` for the \
relative error estimate.";

Clear[cheb`minpos, cheb`approx];
(* Returns the indices of the search starting point of the bracketing sample points.
* Note that the Chebyshev abscissae are reversed *)
cheb`minpos[v_] := Flatten[SparseArray[PeakDetect[-v, 0, 0, Infinity]]["NonzeroPositions"]];

(* Returns the abscissae and function values of a
* Chebyshev approximation of f of absolute error less than tolerance *)
cheb`$keys = {
   "X", (* x-values/abscissae *)
   "Y", (* y-values/function values *)
   "F", (* the function f *)
   "I", (* the interval {x, a, b} *)
   "E", (* error *)
   "C", (* Chebyshev coefficients *)
   "M", (* positions of the local minima *)
   "FM" (* FindMinimum results *)
   };
cheb`data = AssociationMap[None &, cheb`$keys];  (* not needed; used for diagnostics *)
cheb`approx[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, tolerance_, minR_: 4, maxR_: 10] := 
  Module[{vf, xvals, fvals, error, r = minR,
    coeffs},  (* coeffs are not needed; saved in cheb`data *)
   If[Quiet@ListQ[f /. x -> {N@a}],    (* vf = Listable-ized f *)
    vf = Evaluate[f /. x -> #] &,
    vf = Map[Evaluate[f /. x -> #] &, #] &;
    ];
   {xvals, fvals} = NestWhile[
     Function[{xx, ff}, 
        (* recursive bisection of abscissae *)
        With[{new = Rescale[Cos[Pi Range[1., 2^r, 2]/2^r], {-1, 1}, {a, b}]},
         r++;
         {Riffle[xx, new], Riffle[ff, vf[new]]}   (* riffle new values *)
         ]
        ] @@ # &,
     (r++; {#, vf[#]}) &@     (* initial subdivision of {a,b} *)
      Rescale[Cos[Pi Range[0., 2^r]/2^r], {-1, 1}, {a, b}],
     (error =                 (* calculate error from tail of Chebyshev series *)
        Total@Abs@#[[-Max[2, r] ;;]]/Max@Abs[#] &[
          coeffs = FourierDCT[Last@#, 1]]) > tolerance &,
     1,
     1 + maxR - minR
     ];
   If[error > tolerance,      (* check error *)
    Message[chebMinimize::ncv, maxR, a, b, error]
    ];
   cheb`data = 
    AssociationThread[cheb`$keys -> {xvals, fvals, f, {x, a, b}, error, coeffs, {}, {}}];
   {xvals, fvals}
   ];

chebMinimize[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{xvals, fvals, minima, res},
   (* get sample points & values *)
   {xvals, fvals} = 
    cheb`approx[f, {x, a, b}, 
     OptionValue[Tolerance],
     OptionValue[MinRecursion],
     OptionValue[MaxRecursion]];

   (* get positions of minima in fvals *)
   minima = cheb`minpos[fvals];
   If[NumericQ[OptionValue["MaxMinima"]] && 
       Length@minima > OptionValue["MaxMinima"],
    minima = minima[[
       Ordering[fvals[[minima]], OptionValue["MaxMinima"]]
       ]]
    ];
   cheb`data["M"] = minima;

   (* polish minima with FindMinimum *)
   res = With[{msgs = OptionValue[chebMinimize, {opts}, "SuppressMessages", Hold] /.
       {All | Automatic :> Sequence[], None -> {}}},
     msgs /. Hold[m___] :> MinimalBy[First]@
        Quiet[
         cheb`data["FM"] = FindMinimum[f,
             {x,
              xvals[[#]],
              xvals[[Clip[# + 1, {1, Length@xvals}]]], 
              xvals[[Clip[# - 1, {1, Length@xvals}]]]}
             ] & /@ minima,
         m]];
   MapAt[First, Transpose@res, 1]
   ];
```

#### Some analysis of the algorithm

The accuracy of a Chebyshev series approximation can be estimated from the tail of the series:
$$\left|f(x) - \sum_{k=0}^N c_k T_k(x)\right| = 
 \left|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty c_k T_k(x)\right| \le
 \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \left|c_k \right|$$
since $|T_k(x)| = |\cos(k \arccos x)| \le 1$.
It takes $N+1$ Chebyshev sample points to get a series of order $N$.
The accuracy of a Chebyshev series approximation to an oscillatory function generally bounces around the amplitude of the oscillations until the number is sufficiently large. The approximation cannot really get a grip on the function until there is at least one point per extrema, but often, especially for irregular oscillations, it has will be considerable more.  When convergence starts, it will be rapid for an analytic function, and the error can estimated from the last few coefficients of the Chebyshev approximation.

The term `Sin[200 Cos[Pi x/2]^8 x]` used in the extremely oscillatory example above has a "maximum frequency" of `200 / (2 Pi)` near `x == 0`. That would translate to about 127 extrema. We can see that the Chebyshev coefficients $c_k$ start to settle down around $k = 127$, but they do not start their convergence to zero until $k$ is more than $200$. At $k = 460$, the approximation reaches the limit of machine precision. (Note also that the function is odd, which means the odd-order Chebyshev coefficients are theoretically zero. The function also has some very flat minima, which causes `FindMinimum` to complain.)

```
obj = Sin[200 Cos[Pi x/2]^8 x];
chebMinimize[obj, {x, -1, 1}, "SuppressMessages" -> All];  (* load cheb`data *)
cdata = RealExponent@cheb`data["C"];
ListPlot[cdata, PlotRange -> {-18, 2}, GridLines -> {{127, 200, 460}, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A similar thing happens with the other term `Sin[50000 x + 1]/1000`, except that convergence does not start until we have about 50000 points.  Note that the level of the pre-convergent phase is about the amplitude of the function, `1/1000`.

```
obj = Sin[50000 x + 1]/1000;
chebMinimize[obj, {x, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20, "MaxMinima" -> 100]; (* load cheb`data *)
cdata = RealExponent@cheb`data["C"];
ListPlot[cdata, PlotRange -> {-18, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The full example is a combination of these two processes.  Note that oddness of the second term is reflected in the plateau at `10^-3`, which is magnitude of the first term (lower left).
*In general, one should expect that for the algorithm to be guaranteed to be successful, the approximation should have an error much less than this minimum amplitude of the oscillations.*
When this is not known, one can see that a machine-precision approximation is possible. If the oscillations of this order, then it will hopeless anyway, unless the working precision is increased.

```
obj = Sin[50000 x + 1]/1000 + Sin[200 Cos[Pi x/2]^8 x];
chebMinimize[obj, {x, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20, "MaxMinima" -> 100]; (* load cheb`data *)
cdata = RealExponent@cheb`data["C"];
ListPlot[cdata, PlotRange -> {-18, 2}]
GraphicsRow[
 Module[{i, j, plot},
  plot := ListPlot[cdata[[i ;; j]], DataRange -> {i, j}, PlotRange -> {-18, 2}];
  {i = 1; j = 600; plot,
   i = 49500; j = Length@cdata - 15000; plot}
  ], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a closer look at the sampling and local minima.  The sample points are shown in green and red, with the red one being the seeds for `FindMinimum`.  The local minima returned by `FindMinimum` are in cyan.

```
With[{samples = Transpose@{cheb`data["X"], cheb`data["Y"]}},
 Plot[obj, {x, -1, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 60, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], Lighter@Blue}, 
  Background -> Black,
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.004],
    Green, Point[samples],
    PointSize[0.012], Red, Point@samples[[cheb`data["M"]]],
    PointSize[0.005], Cyan, 
    Point[{x, obj} /. cheb`data["FM"][[All, 2]]]},
  Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {0, Scaled[.05]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a close-up of the region where the absolute minimum was found.  We can see that there are at least three sample points per oscillation, just enough to identify good seeds for `FindMinimum`, and that every local minimum has been found.

```
With[{samples = Transpose@{cheb`data["X"], cheb`data["Y"]}},
 Plot[obj, {x, -0.607, -0.6024},
  PlotPoints -> 60, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], Lighter@Blue}, 
  Background -> Black,
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.008],
    Green, Point[samples],
    PointSize[0.015], Red, Point@samples[[cheb`data["M"]]],
    PointSize[0.008], Cyan, 
    Point[{x, obj} /. cheb`data["FM"][[All, 2]]]},
  Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {0, Scaled[.05]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I wonder: once you have the approximate locations of the extrema, why not differentiate the Chebyshev series and then use Newton-Raphson?

Comment: @J.M. Several reasons, I suppose. (1) Keep the code shorter for the post. (2) The original function & its derivative are probably faster. (3) `FindMinimum` does all sorts of checks, in case the initial points are not as good as imagined. It does in fact give warnings (hence `Quiet[]` above), and the reason for bracketing the roots is because in one test it gave a minimum well outside interval, past several local minima. (4) I don't know what to do when the initial point lies on a concave down segment. (I'm sure I could look it up. Someday.)

Comment: @J.M. The better way, I think, it to use a piecewise Chebyshev approximation, differentiate, use the colleague matrices of the pieces, and pick out the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way: A direct search for local minima with `NDSolve`, polished with `NMinimize`, which essentially uses `FindMinimum` on the seeds found (this approach was alluded to at the end [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58256/4999)).

```
{seeds} = Last@Reap@NDSolve[{t'[x] == 1, t[0] == 0, f[x] == y[x],
      WhenEvent[f'[x] > 0, Sow[{x}]]},
     {}, {x, 0, 5}];

{min, sol} = NMinimize[{y[x], 0 <= x <= 5}, x, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "InitialPoints" -> pts}]
```

> NMinimize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

```
(*  {-5.99997, {x -> 1.72776}}  *)
```

The problem with convergence is insufficient working precision.  A fix is to use `WorkingPrecision -> 16` or higher.  At machine precision, the Newton update, which is appproximately $-y'(x)/y''(x) \approx 7\times10^{-10}$, results in no change in value of $y$:

```
Differences@y[{x, x - y'[x]/y''[x]} /. sol]
(*  {0.}  *)
```

Compare at a higher precision:

```
Differences@y[{x, x - y'[x]/y''[x]} /. SetPrecision[sol, 32]]
(*  {-7.896393357752822*10^-16}  *)
```