# Sow in WhenEvent can't extract parameter value of ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, scoping, event-detection, sow-reap

This is a problem I noticed when trying to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163515/1871). Just consider the following toy example:

```
test = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == a, WhenEvent[t == 1, Sow@a]}, 
   x, {t, 0, 2}, a];
test@1; // Reap
(* {Null, {{a$224638}}} *)
```

This behavior becomes annoying when one wants to group the extracted value using the parameter `a` as a tag i.e. the 2nd argument of `Sow`.

How to understand this behavior? Is it possible to `Sow` the parameter value inside `WhenEvent`? If not, what's the best workaround for it?

Comment: When `test@1` is executed, at some point a `Function` is constructed and it appears the argument `a$224638` is rewritten in the standard way by adding `$`; namely the new argument is `a$224638$`. Thus the value of `a` fails to be injected into `Sow[a$224638]`.  WRI might consider it a bug, if you report it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround.

```
test = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == a, b[0] == a, 
    WhenEvent[t == 1, Sow@b[t]]}, x, {t, 0, 2}, {a}, DiscreteVariables -> b];
Reap[test@1;][[2, 1, 1]]
(* 1. *)
```

and `test@2` returns `2.`, as desired.

Answer (score 4):

another workaround is to not use the parametric form:

```
test[a_] := NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == a, 
              WhenEvent[t == 1, Sow@a]}, x, {t, 0, 2}];
test[1]; // Reap
```

> {Null, {{1}}}