# Find peaks, max and min of an interpolation function?

Tags: functions

I'm new in mathematica.

I have a list of values and i don't know how to find some poitns, such as peaks, the max and min of an interpolation function.

```
RA = List[{0, 0.727578}, {0.4, 0.73179}, {0.8, 0.773248}, {1.2, 1.342248}, {1.6, 0.987746}, {2, 0.791317}, {2.4, 1.11788}, {2.8, 0.996614}, {3.2, 0.938749}];

f = Interpolation[RA]

InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 3.2}}, <>]
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Jessica! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Have you seen `FindPeaks[]`?

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58256) might be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

This functionality is included in the [`FindMaxima`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/FindMaxima.nb), [`FindMinima`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/FindMinima.nb) & [`FindExtrema`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/FindExtrema.nb) functions in [my EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo) (the continuous part is based on [this answer by @DanielLichtblau](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5591/6358)).

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master/EcoEvo/EcoEvo.m"]
(* ... or install with: *)
(* PacletInstall["https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/releases/download/v1.1.0/EcoEvo-1.1.0.paclet"] *)
(* then load the package: *) 
(* <<EcoEvo` *)
(* EcoEvo Package Version 1.1.0 (October 22, 2019) *)

FindMaxima[RA]
(* {{1.2, 1.34225}, {2.4, 1.11788}} *)

FindMaxima[f]
(* {{0.171237, 0.75627}, {1.2, 1.34225}, {2.41594, 1.11823}} *)
```

Comment: @AntonAntonov Good idea, thanks!

Comment: These might be a  good candidate for the Wolfram Function Repository, should you wish to make it available in that way.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I might, but I'm mostly holding out for the Paclet Repository!

Comment: The advantage of the Function Repository is that it actually exists (not to get into ontological debates or anything...)

Answer (score 6):

Here is your list and its interpolation. I only made the interpolation smoother:

```
rA = List[{0, 0.727578}, {0.4, 0.73179}, {0.8, 0.773248}, {1.2, 
    1.342248}, {1.6, 0.987746}, {2, 0.791317}, {2.4, 1.11788}, {2.8, 
    0.996614}, {3.2, 0.938749}];

f = Interpolation[rA, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Spline"];
```

Let us plot it:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3.2}]
```

[image]

Now, try this:

```
Map[FindMaximum[f[x], {x, #}] &, {0.1, 1., 2.3}]

(*  {{0.801624, {x -> 0.169875}}, {1.35071, {x -> 
    1.24042}}, {1.13541, {x -> 2.48519}}}   *)

Map[FindMinimum[f[x], {x, #}] &, {0.6, 2.1, 2.9}]

(*  {{0.672974, {x -> 0.605239}}, {0.772641, {x -> 
    1.91542}}, {0.890775, {x -> 3.06279}}}   *)
```

Have fun!