# How can I set a find max value function with parameter in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, maximum

For example, Here is a NDSolve function with a parameter of w

```
s[w_] := NDSolve[{x''[t] == -T1 x'[t] + C1*Ex[x[t], y[t], t, w], 
    y''[t] == -T1 y'[t] + C1*Ey[x[t], y[t], t, w] - g, x[0] == 0, 
    y[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 
    timelimit}];
MMy[t_] = y[t] /. s[7];
ymax = Max[Table[MMy[i], {i, timelimit - 2, timelimit, .00001}]];
```

In this way, I can know the max value when w=7.

Now, how can I set a functin of ymax related to w.

Like  `ymax[w_] :=`

I mean if I want to get the max value of y[t], I only need to change the w in the yman[] function rather than the value in this place `MMy[t_] = y[t] /. s[w]`

If I can set a function `ymax[w]`, I can easily get a series of ymax with different value of w.

I have tried this:

```
MMy[w_, t_] = y[t] /. s[w];
ymax[w_] = Max[Table[MMy[w, i], {i, timelimit - 2, timelimit, .00001}]];
```

It seems not work.

Comment: `Max[y@“ValuesOnGrid” /. s[7]]`?

Comment: The output shows InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>][CurlyDoubleQuote[ValuesOnGrid]]

Comment: How did you enter "CurlyDoubleQuote"???  That's an input error.  Use an ASCII double quote.  [Ah, I guess it was my dumb smartphone.]

Comment: I just copied this ```Max[y@"ValuesOnGrid" /. s[7]]```

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58256/4999

Comment: Ok, I will try, thank you. I also want to limit the range of t in this {timelimit-2, timelimit} to find the max value. So, based on the find max value method in the question, do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the link. I learned a lot from the previous question to get the optimal method to find max value. However, I think, currently, my question is more like a function construction question. Maybe I did not make it clear.

Comment: If you don't need the full solution, use `s[w_] := NDSolve[..., {t, timelimit - 2, timelimit}]` and then the `Max[..]` code would do what you want. Otherwise something like `Max@Select[Transpose[{y@"Grid", y@"ValuesOnGrid"} /. s[7]}], #[[1, 1]] > timelimit - 2 &]` -- I don't have a computer at hand, so the code might need tweaking.

Comment: You probably should define `s[w_]` with `ClearAll[s]; s[w_?NumericQ] :=...` and `MMy` with `:=` instead of `=`.

Comment: Thank fot the suggestion. I tried ```:=``` too, which is very slow and I don't know if I can get the same results. I think the use of ```=``` stores the value of y[t] and will make the calculation of max[Table] very fast.

Comment: If slow, maybe instead of `NDSolve` and `s[w_]`, you should use `s = ParametricNDSolveValue[...]` with `w` as a parameter.  It saves (recent) `NDSolve` results for you internally, so that multiple calls to `s[7]` reuse the `NDSolve` result

Comment: Good point. But I don't know how to get reuslt with two variables using ```ParametricNDSolveValue``` I find examples in the help of ```ParametricNDSolveValue``` only have single variable.