# Finding maximum of 2D interpolating function as a function of one of the variables

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, maximum

I am solving a 2D PDE in space and time b(r,t) and would like to find the maximum value of b in space as a function of time t.

Using the solution for maximising a 1D interpolating function from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58244/find-maximum-value-of-interpolation-function-obviously-wrong-result), I tried the following minimal working example, but it doesn't work:

```
largerad = 10;
tmax = 80;
b0 = 0.1;

pde = {D[b[r, t], t] == D[b[r, t], r, r] - b[r, t]};
ic = {b[r, 0] == b0};
bc = {Derivative[1, 0][b][largerad, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][b][0, t] == 0}; 

zsolv = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, {b}, {r, 0, largerad}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.01];

Nbins = 200;

mytableb = 
  Table[NMaximize[{ b[r, t] /. zsolv, 0 <= r <= rad}, r, 
    Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"], {t, 0, tmax, tmax/Nbins}];
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for an alternative implementation that would give b_max(t) as a list of values?

**Edit:** I'm looking for a general solution, also for PDE's that are not exactly solvable using DSolve. I just gave this as a simple example.

Comment: `DSolve [{pde, ic, bc}, b , {r, 0, largerad}, {t, 0, tmax} ] ` evaluates the exact solution `{b -> Function[{r, t}, 0.1 2.71828^(-1. t)]}}` which doesn't depend on r!

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm looking for a general solution, also for PDE's that are not exactly solvable using DSolve. I just gave this as a simple example. I clarified that in an edit.

Comment: In my comment I tried to emphasize that your example has no unique solution, that's why a numerical solution can't be found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy approximation is to pick out the max values from the interpolation grid.

```
bval = b@"ValuesOnGrid" /. First@zsolv // Transpose;

bmax = Interpolation[
   Transpose@{Last[b@"Coordinates" /. First@zsolv], Max /@ bval}];
ListLogPlot[bmax, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem!